# Why does this code work with everything, except with a exit command

Tags: python, keyboard

The Code

```
import keyboard

keyboard.on_press_key("p", lambda _:sys.exit())   # if i write something else than sys.exit than it 
                                                 #does work
```

It doesnt happen anything, no error,nothing.
I found the error on stackoverflow, but this was 8 years ago, so the solution didnt work at all

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to access `exit` as a field. Add parentheses to make it a function call.

```py
import keyboard

keyboard.on_press_key("p", lambda _:sys.exit()))
```